# Charles Certificate Installation Error on UWP

Tags: uwp, ssl-certificate, charles-proxy

How can I install the Charles certificate on UWP mobile?

I'm using charles v4.0.1 and when I download the certificate to install it, the following error is shown:

```
Your certificates weren't installed
...file might be unsopported or corrupt..
Error: 0xc1130006
```